# Cutting the minimum spanning tree

Tags: java, image-segmentation, jgrapht

I'm doing a Java project that requires the following :

Input: A gray-scale image with P pixels, and a number R

Output: An image segmented into R regions

1. Map the image onto a primal weighted graph.
2. Find a minimum spanning tree of the graph.
3. Cut the minimum spanning tree at the R – 1 most costly edges.
4. Assign the average tree vertex weight to each vertex in each tree in the forest
5. Map the partition onto a segmentation image

I did the first two steps:

- I mapped the image onto a weighted graph by `JGraphT`.
- I mapped each pixel onto a vertex of the graph in a one-to-one relationship with the pixel intensity assigned to the vertex weight, and the edges are the nearest neighbors of each vertex with weights of the absolute value of the difference between the weights of the vertices.
- Then I found the minimun spanning trees by `KruskalMinimumSpanningTree`.

But I am stuck in steps 3 and 4. 
What does it mean to cut the MST that I found at the `R – 1` most costly edges and then assign the average tree vertex weight?

Comment: [FAQ on how to question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and [Make it Minimal, Complete and Verfiable Example(MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009602/jgraph-general-traversal-forest-traversal

Comment: Tried to clarify the question. I don't understand what your second step was, maybe you can rewrite?